# Postion the dialog on button click in ASP.Net C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have several buttons on different places on the page. I want to position the dialog on button click exact on the place where my mouse is clicked. following is positioning on window. How to position on my button mouse click place?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: window },
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
This is a simple popup
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can position dialog relative to the button which was clicked. You could also fix position by adding or subtracting from `left` or `top`. It should look something like this:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function () {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: $btn },
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

```css
.btn {
    margin: 100px 300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' rel="stylesheet" ></link>

<button class="btn">Button</button>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
        This is a simple popup
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I added but $btn not working. Then I added like this position: { my: "left+100 top+20", at: "left top", of: $('#btnPopup') } it is working but its not placing at left+100 top+20 position. It on left and top position. I want to be on button click position.

Comment: @Raja take a look at the snippet I've added. You are using deprecated `live` method, maybe because of that, `this` does not point to click target. You should use event delegation, like in example above, it does same thing, but works more effectively.